# How to redirect to another page after AJAX request completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to post some data through a clickable row. I did write some code, it works, but it did not redirect to another page. How can I redirect to another page? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickableRow tr').click(function (event) {
        var advertentieId = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("Advertentie", { advertentieId: advertentieId });
    });
});
```

Comment: have you checked browser's console to see if you are getting any errors?

Comment: You can use `window.location.assign('url')`. However, if you're going to redirect anyway the point of the AJAX request is a little moot

Comment: @vijayP, sorry i have edited my question. My code works actualy, but it does not redirect to another page. Then i used loaction.href to redirect to another page, but it does not support post. How can i redirect with post?

Comment: you are going to have to return the URL to where you want to redirect from the post call, then call `window.location.assign` on that url

Comment: your question makes not that much sense. You are using Ajax (to post data without reloading) and in the same time you want to post to another page?

Comment: I believe you can't use `ajax` for this. Instead of that; have a `<form>` with proper `action` and `method` specified in it. Also have one hidden form field in that. Now on `tr` click; set the hidden form field and submit the form. It will POST the form and by standard mechanism you will get redirected depending upon your response.

Comment: Thanx @vijay i will search for form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> redirect to another page after AJAX request completes

jquery [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) has a success callback.

You can use this to be notified when the post has completed and then redirect:

```
 $.post(
    "Advertentie", 
    { advertentieId: advertentieId },
    function() {
        location.href='newurl';
    });
```

> `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`
>
> **success**
>
> Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

---

It could be that you are expecting a form *submit* to redirect (in which case, do not use ajax/$.post), but I have answered the question as asked.

Comment: Thanx @freedomn-m i will search for form submit.